# Checking smoothnes of a map defined on a parametrization of $T^2$

Tags: differential-geometry

The book says: "We can represent points in $T^2$ as pairs $(e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_2})$."

I understand that this is a parametrization of the torus as a product of circles in $\mathbb{C}^2$. But then i am given a map defined in terms of the parametrization like so:

$$(e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_2}) \mapsto F(e^{i\theta_1},e^{i\theta_2}) \in \mathbb{R}^3$$

How am is supposed to check it's smoothness? what are the actual charts on $T^2$?

I can translate the whole question to an atlas of my liking but that seems extremely redundant.

Comment: it will depend on the smoothness of $F$

Comment: @abel what will depend?

Comment: the smoothness of the map $(t_1, t_2) \rightarrow f(t_1, t_2)$ depends  on the smoothness of $f$ as a function of two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably better to think of this as a map from $\mathbb R^2$ (parameterized by $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$) to $T^2$, with $\mathbb C^2$ as an intermediate space.

This map is actually the universal covering map for $T^2$, and is smooth (prove this using your own charts, or whatever else you like), and locally has a smooth inverse (by something like the homotopy lifting property).

It can therefore be used to check smoothness of composite functions:  You look at
$$
\bar{F} : \mathbb R^2 \to T^2 \to \mathbb R^3 : (\theta_1, \theta_2) \mapsto F(e^{i\theta_1}, e^{i\theta_2})
$$
and check whether $\bar{F}$ is smooth or not as a function from 2-space to 3-space. That's usually straightforward (compute partials, etc.). And then $F$ is smooth if and only if $\bar{F}$ is smooth.

Comment: i am out of here.

Comment: So basically I have a smooth function $\overline F: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ that factorizes through the torus (which is covered by $\mathbb{R}^2$) and so i can conclude that the function from the torus to $\mathbb{R}^3$ is also smooth (because it inherits its smooth structure from $\mathbb{R}^2$)?

Comment: That's pretty much correct, yes. You need to know not only that the unnamed map from $R^2$ to $T^2$ -- let's call it $p$ -- is smooth, but that its inverse exists locally and is smooth as well.  Otherwise, $p$ could be a constant map, and you'd conclude that every map $F : T^2 \to R^3$ was smooth!

Comment: What i meant by "factorizes" is that it factorizes as a composition with the covering map. In that case i hope my generalization holds...

Comment: Yes. I was trying to explain that   your statement holds because of certain properties of the covering map $p$ (which could apply to other maps you encounter later).